# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un campo como único en un campo one2many?

Tags: python, constraints, openerp

Requiero que un campo "fecha" a nivel de líneas no se puedan repetir para un mismo registro de empleado cuando dicho campo se encuentra en otro modelo, es decir que la relación entre modelos es un campo one2many, pero al momento de agregar la restricción `_sql_constraints` se muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> ```
> XmlHttpRequestError Not Found
> No handler found.
> ```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
class ratio_costo_empleado(osv.osv):
    _name= "costo_laboral.ratio_costo_empleado"

    _columns={
        'empleado': fields.many2one('hr.employee', string='Empleado', required=True),
        'lineas_fechas':fields.one2many('costo_laboral.ratio_costo_empleado_historico','id_ratio', string='Detalle ratio por fecha')    
    }

class ratio_costo_empleado_historico(osv.osv):
    _name= "costo_laboral.ratio_costo_empleado_historico"

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('qmex_fechasx_uniq', 'unique(fecha)', 'La fecha que esta intentando ingresar ya existe!'),
    ]

    _columns={
        'id_ratio':fields.many2one('costo_laboral.ratio_costo_empleado','ratio_id'),
        'fecha': fields.date('Fecha', required=True),
        'ratio': fields.float('Ratio',digits=(3,2)),
        'ratio_alternativo': fields.float('Ratio Alternativo',digits=(4,2))    
    }
```